# Can GTA V Online work between Xbox 360 and Xbox One

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one

Can someone on an Xbox 360 play GTA online with people on Xbox One and vice versa? Some guys in a lobby said he was on the 360 playing with me (I have an Xbox one) but I have a feeling he wasn't in the right state of mind. Is it possible?

Comment: No. Cross-generation, cross-platform, and cross-console play is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

No. Cross platform play is currently not possible between Xbox 360 and Xbox One in *any* game, let alone GTA V.

Comment: thats applicable to PS3 and PS4? If a friend is playing in ps3 and I play in ps4, we will never "see" in gta online? (I asked it on: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201733/gta-v-online-ps3-and-ps4)

Comment: I don't know anything about PlayStation Network, but I don't see how they could be compatible. The next generation version of the game supports, among other things that the original version doesn't, 30 players in the same session.