# GTA-V, Online PS3 and PS4

Tags: ps3, psn, grand-theft-auto-online, ps4

I have PS4 and GTA-V, my friend has the GTA-V too, but he have PS3. I have PSNPlus, but my friend  not yet. The reason he don't have it, is because we want to try to play GTA-V online, but togheter.

My question is:

When he buy PSN-Plus, we will be able to play togheter online? I ask it because we have different PlayStations..

Comment: Ok, I'll check it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, online play between PS3 and PS4 isn't possible in GTA V.

Though PS3/4 cross play is apparently [*technically* possible](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2013/10/30/ps4-the-ultimate-faq-north-america/), most developers choose not to, probably due to the difficulties in maintaining balance between different versions of the game.

That aside, I imagine that crossplay in GTAV would be almost impossible to work out due to the differences in the maximum number of players between the two versions (30 in current, 16 in last gen, I believe).

Comment: Ouch! That is not a good notice....  Well.. Thanks for all!

Answer (score -1):

I've heard talk of it. It's possible but it would require the ps4 owners to willingly play in a server running the game at ps3 standards. Meaning several features exclusive to ps4 would be gone. But it's possible in the future and rockstar is known to do things even when not popular. If enough people want it they'll do it. I know people who would play a 16 person round just to play with friends

Comment: Are you saying it would be technically possible for the devs to implement (as the accepted answer says) or that it's possible for users to do this (in which case mention how)?